# Adding columns from SELECT queries next to each other

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to queries that return the following tables:

```
foo | bar
----+----
  1 |   2
  5 |   6
```

and

```
baz | qux
----+----
  3 |   4
  7 |   8
```

I want to combine them to return the following table

```
foo | bar | baz | qux
----+-----+-----+----
  1 |   2 |   3 |   4
  5 |   6 |   7 |   8
```

There's no condition on which they join other than the order they're in after their individual `SELECT` statements. This is probably a comically easy problem, but I can't seem to figure out how to word the search to return me what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add that condition and join those results using [row_number()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) function:

```
SELECT T1.foo, T1.bar, T2.baz, T2.qux
FROM 
  (SELECT table1.*, row_number() OVER () as rnum1 FROM (query1) table1) T1
  JOIN (SELECT table2.*, row_number() OVER () as rnum2 FROM (query2) table2) T2
    ON T1.rnum1 = t2.rnum2
```

Depending on your situation, there can be `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` instead.